# Recalculation of indices

Tags: jquery, indexing

I have such functionality for adding / removing inputs. Indexes must be continuous and incremental to work correctly. However, when some input is deleted, the index continues to store the value of the input and an interruption of the sequence appears, which causes the data from the database to be returned incorrectly. How can the indexes be recalculated on every deletion? I tried only this method, but it didn't work:

```
var j = 0, i = 0;
    $(".key").each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr('name', 'properties['+i+'][key]');
      i++;
  });
    $(".value").each(function(j) {
    $(this).attr('name', 'properties['+j+'][key]');
      j++;
  });
```

```js
var i = 0;
$("#addRow").click(function () {
        var html = '';
        html += '<div id="inputFormRow">';
        html += '<div class="input-group mb-3">';
        html += i+'<input type="text" name="properties['+i+'][key]" class="key form-control m-input ml-3" placeholder="Key" autocomplete="off">';
        html += i+'<input type="text" name="properties['+i+'][value]" class="value form-control m-input ml-3" placeholder="Value" autocomplete="off">';
        html += '<div class="input-group-append ml-3">';
        html += '<button id="removeRow" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>';
        html += '</div>';
        html += '</div>';

        i++;

        $('#newRow').append(html);
    });
// remove row
$(document).on('click', '#removeRow', function () {
    $(this).closest('#inputFormRow').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="newRow"></div>
<button id="addRow" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Add field</button>
```

If this code can be improved, it might work. The correct index is stored, but for some reason, each item field is set to the same number and not incremented.

```
$(document).on('click', '#removeRow', function () {
    i--;
    $(this).closest('#inputFormRow').remove();
    for (i = 0; i < $('.key').length; i++){
      $('.key').attr('name', 'properties['+i+'][key]');
      $('.value').attr('name', 'properties['+i+'][value]');

    };
});
```

```js
var i = 0;
$("#addRow").click(function () {
        var html = '';
        html += '<div id="inputFormRow">';
        html += '<div class="input-group mb-3">';
        html += '<input type="text" name="properties['+i+'][key]" class="key form-control m-input ml-3" placeholder="Key" autocomplete="off">';
        html += '<input type="text" name="properties['+i+'][value]" class="value form-control m-input ml-3" placeholder="Value" autocomplete="off">';
        html += '<div class="input-group-append ml-3">';
        html += '<button id="removeRow" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>';
        html += '</div>';
        html += '</div>';

        i++;

        $('#newRow').append(html);
    });
// remove row
$(document).on('click', '#removeRow', function () {
    i--;
    $(this).closest('#inputFormRow').remove();
    for (i = 0; i < $('.key').length; i++){
      $('.key').attr('name', 'properties['+i+'][key]');
      $('.value').attr('name', 'properties['+i+'][value]');

    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="newRow"></div>
<button id="addRow" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Add field</button>
```

Comment: If this is dependent on something from the database, pull that information from the database and write it to the HTML. Then you won't need to worry about indexing.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest is just reindex them all. You could wait until just before you submit but it's not that big a task to do for each action.

Note you are repeating IDs so they have been changed to classes since IDs are unique by definition

The following loops over each row and gets the index of that row to pass to the field index values

```js
   
function reIndex(){
   const reg=/\[\d+\]/;
  // `each` callback of row provides index needed
  $('.inputFormRow').each(function(i){
        $(this).find('.key,.value').attr('name', function(_, curr){
            return curr.replace(reg, '[' + i +']')
       });  
  });
  
  // for demo only set values with names to see effects
  // remove this in production
  $('.key,.value').val(function(){
      return this.name
  })
}


$("#addRow").click(function () {
        let i = 100
        var html = '';
        html += '<div class="inputFormRow">';
        html += '<div class="input-group mb-3">';
        html += '<input type="text" name="properties['+i+'][key]" class="key form-control m-input ml-3" placeholder="Key" autocomplete="off">';
        html += '<input type="text" name="properties['+i+'][value]" class="value form-control m-input ml-3" placeholder="Value" autocomplete="off">';
        html += '<div class="input-group-append ml-3">';
        html += '<button  type="button" class="removeRow btn btn-danger">Delete</button>';
        html += '</div>';
        html += '</div>';       

        $('#newRow').append(html);
        reIndex()
    });
// remove row
$(document).on('click', '.removeRow', function () {
   
    $(this).closest('.inputFormRow').remove();
    reIndex()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="newRow"></div>
<button id="addRow" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Add field</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've replaced your html concatenation with a literal string, which is slightly cleaner, also replacing `id` which would be duplicated with a class.

I've also introduced a data attribute to hold the index of the row.

```js
$("#addRow").click(function() {
  let i = $("#newRow .inputFormRow").length;
  var html = `
        <div class="inputFormRow" data-index=${i}>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
        ${i}<input type="text" name="properties[${i}][key]" class="key form-control m-input ml-3" placeholder="Key" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="text" name="properties[${i}][value]" class="value form-control m-input ml-3" placeholder="Value" autocomplete="off" >
        <div class="input-group-append ml-3">
        <button id="removeRow" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
        </div>
        </div>`

  $('#newRow').append(html);
});
// remove row
$(document).on('click', '#removeRow', function() {
  //Get the target row
  let thisRow = $(this).closest('.inputFormRow');
  //Get the index from the data attribute for the current row
  let thisIndex = parseInt($(thisRow).data("index"), 10);
 
  //Loop through subsequent rows
  $(thisRow).nextAll().each(function() {    
    //Reset the index data attribute for this element
    //Note that "this" now referes to the current elelment from the loop
    $(this).data("index", thisIndex)
    //Update the inputs indices for this element
    $(this).find(".key").attr("name", `properties[${thisIndex}][key]`);
    $(this).find(".value").attr("name", `properties[${thisIndex}][value]`);
    //For Demo Only 
    //$(this).find(".value").val(`idx: ${$(this).data("index")}`);
    //Increment this index
    thisIndex++;
  });
  //Remove the row
  $(thisRow).remove();
  
  //For Demo only
  $(".value").each(function(){
    $(this).val("data-index: " + $(this).closest(".inputFormRow").data("index"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="newRow"></div>
<button id="addRow" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Add field</button>
```

Comment: Think you will find it will be easy to get duplicates of `data-index`

Comment: @charlietfl The data in `data-index` should still be unique, as is the name attribute. As the actual attribute for data is not updated, yes there will be duplicates if inspected via dev tools. Replacing `.data("index" [, value])`  with `.attr("data-index" [, value])` could address this if needed

Comment: What I mean is decrement `i` and create a new row the last two will have same `thisIndex`. Also FYI if `data(prop)` is numeric it will return as number not string

Comment: @charlietfl, yup forgot that with `prop` and `i` isn't really needed anyway. The update calculates the required index on creation. No need to really store that in a variable that is operated on in separate methods. And you are quite correct, re-indexing is cleaner.